# Where is file after create in android, where it is?

Tags: java, android

I create a file in android emulator, after that I try it on phone but I don't have the same dir. Where can I find my file on PHONE?

```
public  void costam (String text)
    {

          try {             
              FileOutputStream fOut = context.openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",
                                                      context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
              OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 


              osw.write(text);

              osw.flush();
              osw.close();
          }catch(Exception e){ }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's here:

```
/data/data/domain.package.AppName/samplefile.txt
```

Comment: I don't have /data/data/... dir on phone.

Comment: You need root access on your device to access that file with a file browser. DDMS won't help you either (it has no permission to access those files). It's in the root directory, not your SD card root. To get the file without root access you need to write in on the SD card (with your application) so you can access the file without the need of a rooted device. Hint: Root restriction doesn't apply to the emulator.